# Display images stored in Spring MVc

Tags: spring, jsp

I have uploaded some images and it got saved into a directory in this path:
C:\Users\user\Inoesis Spring Projects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\HDTS/photos.

```
 I have uploaded some images and it got saved into a directory in this path:
C:\Users\user\Inoesis Spring Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\HDTS/photos. Handler method in the Controller:


       @RequestMapping(value={"/", "home"})
        public ModelAndView showIndex(){
            return new ModelAndView("index", "artistList", artistService.getArtistsByLikes());
        }

view : index.jsp

    <c:if test="${not empty artistList }">
            <c:forEach  items="${artistList }" var="artistInfo">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <c:out value="${ artistInfo.stageName}"/> </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <img alt="" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/photos/${artistInfo.photoName}">
                        </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
                        </div><!-- /.panel panel-primary -->

            </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
            </c:forEach>

            </c:if>


Pls note my project is HDTS.
How do i display them on a jsp page.
thanks
```

Pls note my project is HDTS.
How do i display them on a jsp page.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can send the uploaded image name to the requested page and use the **getContextPath()** defined in [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) to get complete URL to uploaded image.

`<%=request.getContextPath()%>` will give /wtpwebapps/HDTS

So your `<img />` should look like :

`<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/photos/${image_name}"/>`

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding! Cheers!!

Comment: i have included some snippets.

Comment: could you debug and check what value is getting populated for ${artistInfo.photoName}.

Also close the <img> tag.

Comment: I debugged and it's showing the exact image name only the part was not found

Comment: You should explicitly specify the image extension to the request. Something like image_name.extension like jpeg, png etc. Complete filename with extension.

Comment: Yes. I have the filename saved as a string to  table and so there's no need for the extension. The challenge is how to specify the file path. If it's hardcoded it may break once the application is deployed to production environment. What's the solution to this?

Comment: I dont know how i can do a snapshot and display but its basically all the form data and the image original plus its extension. I really want to know whats the best practice for uploading files. Is better we define our own path or rely on the  request.getContextPath()%>/photos/ to set it for us?

Comment: I have made some progress debugging and i notice this request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"photos/ instead of what you suggested but another issue as cropped up; Though the path to images is now referenced correctly  but nothing showed on the page and when i inspect the element i noticed this error:  Not allowed to load local resource